# htaccess redirect problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get my .htaccess to redirect all requests to the /blogs directory, except for requests that start with /staff.  This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^staff(.*)$ staff/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogs/$1 [L]
```

It works fine for every case, except when I do http://mydomain.com/staff or http://mydomain.com/staff/alice in which case I get a 500 Internal Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, you can use staff$1 instead of staff/$1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^staff/  - [L]
RewriteRule !^blogs/ blogs%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is logged to `error.log`?  The error may be coming from either `mod_rewrite` or from your application itself.